# How to set variable value conditionally

Tags: java, java-8

I am trying to set variable value based on conditions and I want to know if there is a better way to do this in Java 8 rather than using multiple if else or switch statements.

I need to set Request Number based on String values

123 for foo,
123 for bar,
456 for xyz,
000 as default value i.e for any other string value.

```
if(someString.equalsIgnorecase("foo")){
x = someObj.setRequestNumber(123);
}

else if(someString.equalsIgnorecase("bar")){
x = someObj.setRequestNumber(123);
}

else if(someString.equalsIgnorecase("xyz")){
x = someObj.setRequestNumber(456);
}

else{
x = someObj.setRequestNumber(000);
}
```

Comment: I dont think there is a better way. You could create a method (String) -> int if this task is repetitive. Otherwise you could use enums. One more thing. You could combine the first if and else if statements in one if

Comment: How many strings for comparison you can have in total?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: the code has been updated adding a `toLowerCase` when asking the value connected to a particular key. By the way, a key should be uniquely identified and the OP should decide if using lower cases or upper cases for the keys instead of changing the code making ignore case comparisons.

You can create a `Map<String, Integer>` and use it to set your value (this solution works also in older versions of java, eventually for versions before java 5 don't use generics):

```
// Init the map with the values for each key
Map<String, Integer> values = new HashMap<>();
values.put("foo", 123);
values.put("bar", 123);
values.put("xyz", 456);

// Use the values map to set your value 
someObject.setRequestNumber(value.getOrDefault(someString.toLowerCase(), 0));
```

Use the [`getOrDefault`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#getOrDefault-java.lang.Object-V-) method to set a default value if none of the key is present in the values map:

> Returns the value to which the specified key is mapped, or defaultValue if this map contains no mapping for the key.

Note that if you need to assign the value 000 as default value this is not a n `int`. It must be set as a `String` to hold all the three zeros. Changing it to a String is simple just change the code as follow:

```
// Init the map with the values for each key
Map<String, String> values = new HashMap<>();
values.put("foo", "123");
values.put("bar", "123");
values.put("xyz", "456");

// Use the values map to set your value 
// The method setRequestNumber must receive a String
someObject.setRequestNumber(value.getOrDefault(someString, "000"));
```

As alternative using the switch the best is to create a method like the following (since java 7):

```
 public String getValueFromKey(String key) {
    switch(key.toLowerCase()) {
        case "foo":
        case "bar":      // You can combine multiple case
           return "123"; // You can exit directly with a return instead 
                         // of saving the result in a variable and use a break
        case "xyz":
           return "456";
        default:         // Use the default to set the handle any value not previously handled  
           return "000";  
 }

 ...
 someObj.setRequestNumber(getValueFromKey(someString));
```

Comment: In this specific case, `new TreeMap<>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER)` would be more appropriate than `new HashMap<>()`.

Comment: TreeMap works searching on binary balanced trees, HashMap works with a hash of keys. Research on a TreeMap happens in O(log(n)), in a HashMap happens in O(1), so theoretically a HashMap performs better than a TreeMap.In this case (3, 4 keys and values) any additional structure is not needed in terms of performance (both in terms of memory and speed of execution) so using a switch case will be better.  By the way not always writing the best performing code means writing the best code. A cleaner code is generally better so the Map solution happens cleaner. Better a TreeMap for space than HashMap

Comment: @Holger I used a HashMap only because it is a more known data structure by people with a medium-low knowledge of the Java ecosystem.

Comment: This has nothing to do with performance. The OP’s code clearly suggests that a *case insensitive* comparison is intended.

Comment: CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER doesn't sound like it means case-insensitive key lookup.

Comment: Ignoring one or two strange cases, converting keys to all lower or all upper case before insertion or lookup will generally suffice.

Comment: ReL CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER -- well, imagine that: it **does** result in case-insensitive lookups.   I verified by experiment.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
switch (someString.toUpperCase()) {
  case "XYZ":
    myNum = 1;
    break;
  case "FOO":
    myNum = 2;
    break;
  case "BAR":
  case "ANOTHER_BAR":
    myNum = 3;
    break;
  default:
    myNum = -1;
    break;
}
```

From now on, with the new Switch features (JDK 14+), you can even simplify the Switch statement! Link: https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/361

Comment: is this Java 8 ?

Comment: @VeKe This is valid in any version of Java.

Comment: @kaya3 no, switching on strings was new in Java 8, so this is not valid in versions of Java older than Java 8.

Comment: @kaya3 ` is a better way to do this in Java 8` OP is asking about Java 8

Comment: ah yea that makes sense actually.

Comment: yeah, starting from jdk 8 for strings!

Comment: Perfect @NakarukatoshiUzumaki, it just skipped out of my mind that this is Java 8 feature

Comment: The switch handling strings is available since java 7, not 8!

Comment: @DavideLorenzoMARINO ups, true! My fault, sorry

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you could replace the first two `if` statements with one:

```
if (someString.equalsIgnorecase("foo") || someString.equalsIgnorecase("bar")) {
    x = someObj.setRequestNumber(123);
} else if (someString.equalsIgnorecase("xyz")) {
    x = someObj.setRequestNumber(456);
} else {
    x = someObj.setRequestNumber(000);
}
```

Another way is to create a `Map`, and lookup the result from the map:

```
Map<String, Integer> map = Map.of("foo", 123, "bar", 123, "xyz", 456);

x = map.getOrDefault(someString.toLowerCase(), 0);
```

(Note: `Map.of(...)` was added in Java 9, if you're using an earlier version of Java you'll have to add the elements separately with `map.put("foo", 123);` etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Use a map.

Initialization:

```
   Map<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
   map.put("foo", 123);
   map.put("bar", 123);
   map.put("xyz", 456);
    :
```

Use:

```
Integer req = map.get(someString.toLowerCase());
if (req != null)
     someObj.setRequestNumber(req);
else
     error("....!");
```

This trades off a little initialization code for simplicity elsewhere, and is worthwhile if you have to make 'many' such lookups and have 'many' strings to look up.

Comment: There is no reason to give a minus to this answer that is the best approach to set a value without using a swith or if else if

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Map

```
 Map<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("foo",123);
        map.put("bar",123);
        map.put("xyz",456);
        
        x= map.get(someString);
```

When faced with many conditions see if you can apply polymorphism .
https://refactoring.com/catalog/replaceConditionalWithPolymorphism.html